# Online Learning Resources for Discrete Mathematics

Tags: reference-request, education, discrete-mathematics

Are there any good Discrete mathematics learning web resources with problem sets?

Comment: If you can afford or access it in a library, check out [GPK's  Concrete Mathematics](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/gkp.html). It has loads of exercises with solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the perfect place for you, I really enjoyed it myself:

[Discrete Mathematics lecture series on infocobuild](http://www.infocobuild.com/education/learn-through-videos/mathematics/discrete-mathematics.html)

Everything I learned is from that site.

Answer (score 10):

There is a whole course being offered by Udacity<sup>*</sup>, [Logic and Discrete Mathematics](http://www.udacity.com/overview/Course/cs221/CourseRev/1), which has interactive quizzes and homework assignments.

The course description is as follows:

> This course presents key concepts in discrete mathematics, specifically, elementary propositional logic and elements of enumerative combinatorics, elementary number theory, and graph theory, with partially ordered sets and lattices as a unifying concept.

<sub>*I am not affiliated with them in any way, but I have taken some of their prior courses</sub>

Comment: Link seems dead

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc Yeah, they have paywalled a lot of their courses at this point, and it no longer seems to be listed.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Kenneth Rosen's text "Discrete mathematics and its applications" is available on archive.org's opensource collection [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjXwMzZnbniAhUR448KHYXpDVcQFjACegQIBhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Farchive.org%2Fdetails%2FDiscreteMathematicsAndItsApplications7thEditionKennethH.Rosen&usg=AOvVaw0_4JIerYsTH5ODMnHaqd-M).  The PDF of the ebook can be downloaded (legally, it looks like).

Rosen's text is a classic for introductory discrete mathematics.  Solutions to odd-numbered exercises are in the book.